# Styling Tables - How to use column groups to modify TH tag located in that column

Tags: css, css-tables

I am new to modifying column groups in tables and trying to learn how label the css to make the TH in the featured column group a specific background color, as well as the TD's inside that column group.  My only problem is, I don't know how to setup the CSS to reflect ONLY those sections.

I have made an example table located at: http://jsbin.com/ocezon/1/edit

If I didn't phrase this correctly, please let me know and I will try to explain further.  I have labeled the TH and the TD's I'd like to be able to modify using the #table-5 #featured attribute assigned by column group.

I've tried code like `#table-5 #featured TH { background: #000; }` but that didn't work.

---

EDIT:  I found out that this probably isn't possible (and after trying numerous methods, I can't make it work either)...so I decided to give the answer to One Trick Pony for suggesting a method that does work; however, I slightly modified this method to make it easy to modify in the future: http://jsbin.com/icasom/1/edit

Comment: I've modified the entire column group and changed the background red.  What I want to do is to be able to modify JUST the TH inside that column group..I tried  `#table-5 #featured TH { background: #000; }` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `colgroups`, you can style the 3rd child of each row:

```
#table-5 th:nth-child(3){ 
  background: blue;
}

#table-5 tr td:nth-child(3){
  background: #C0000E;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ocezon/3

---

I modified this to make it easier to work with multiple tables and make modifying in the future easier: http://jsbin.com/icasom/1/edit

Comment: only problem with this, is I am labeling the column groups by a "featured" tag.  So every table using this style won't be using the 3rd child of each row.  It will all depend on which "package" (colgroup) I decide to make the featured column group.  The only way I really know how to do this (to make editing easy in the future) is to use column groups.  The packages won't be changing much, but which one is the featured package will change.

Comment: So move the featured ID on the table and apply the styles on #featured

Comment: But that won't help me be able to modify specific parts of the table based on the featured column.  I want to be able to change the color of the TH tag UNDER the featured column group.  I've been able to modify the ENTIRE column group, but not independent parts.

Comment: `colgroup` identifies columns just like `nth-child` would (by index). I fail to see how can you decide which column to make featured then. If the featured column has a different position in other tables, then you'll just have to add styles for each one (...or use javascript :)

Comment: If I have 3 of the exact same table on 1 page. All 3 will have to have different names, which would require a lot more CSS for each table...Lets say on Table 1 the featured column is 3, but only table 2 and 3 the featured colujmn is 2.  That would be horrible to be able to edit that in css for each table independently. Lets say I want to go in and modify and change the featured columns. The way I'm doing it, its 1 table CSS, and I just have to go in and change the id="featured" on the col groups..the way you are describing it, I'd have to go in and modify the CSS for each independent table.

Comment: I'm styling 1 table that can be used over and over again on different parts of the website ( and maybe even multiple tables on same page)  rather than independent tables with their own CSS associated with each one.

Comment: An alternative is to add a class to each TD/TH, like `.featured` and style that. But I don't see why having a few more lines of CSS would be a problem...

Comment: Then...here's what I'd have to do...I'd have to go in and modify EVERY row under that package to change the featured package.  Some of these tables are going to have A LOT of rows.  That would be wayyy too much work when I could just figure out how to modify the TH and TD's all at once under a specific column group.  If you don't know how, I understand..but the way you are explaining it, I will have to do a lot more work just to  accomplish the same goal.

Comment: So after finding out that this is not possible yet, I have managed to make this work.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

your table has a strange HTML structure, colgroup and th not even wrap in a tr :

```
<table id="table-5">
 <colgroup> 
   <col class="row" />
  <col class="basic"/>
  <col class="premium" id="featured"/>
  <col class="enterprise"/>
</colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>row</th>
        <th>basic</th>
        <th>premium (modify this TH)</th>
        <th>enterprise</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah (modfy this TD)</td>
            <td>blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah (modfy this TD)</td>
            <td>blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah</td>
            <td>blah (modfy this TD)</td>
            <td>blah</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

you could maybe add somme rgba color to darken your background-colors:
http://jsbin.com/ocezon/9/ http://jsbin.com/ocezon/9/edit

Comment: I know the table structure wasn't perfect.  I made the table as a quick demonstration.  I want to modify JUST the TH under a specific column.  Is this possible?  Basically all the column's TH tags are silver, but I want the featured column's TH tag to be blue. (as an example)

Comment: no it is not, cause background-color is applied underneath of tr. then , beside that , you cannot from inside element , go sibbling an adjacent element of it's parent. At least not before CSS level 4 and parent selector will be usable. You need js to help you out there :)

Comment: I only proposed you a fake or a compromise with rgba() :)

Comment: I understand , but your answer didn't really asnwer my question at all.  All you did was style the table differently overall.  My only concern is to modify a specific TH, or a specific TD under a specific column.  I understand if its not possible, but that was my question.  I've never messed with column groups before, so wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: did you miss my earlier comment ? .... CSS at this time cannot do it :) and col doesn't not give background to tr, th or anything else, its drawn in table behind everything else :).

Comment: okay , sorry for you, , actually , i think mysel styling from col not powerfull enough :)

Comment: Oh no I got that and appreciate it, was just saying all your "answer" did was style the table in a different way.  My question was mainly just for information purposes.  I'm not actually using that table I put in the question (it was just a demonstration of what I was trying to do).  I do appreciate your help.